# Why does this SQL query returns data in descending order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to understand why this query produces results in descending order

```
SELECT
    DateDiff(minute, convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(MSH_07_DateTime, 1, 8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(MSH_07_DateTime, 9, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(MSH_07_DateTime, 11, 2), 100), GetDate()) 
FROM 
    EPDBHL7.DBO.[HL7MSH] 
WHERE
    MessageStatus <> 'ok'
```

Comment: Without an ORDER BY the order is unspecified.

Comment: If you don't want to dig into topics like execution-plans etc. the answer to your question can only be "by sheer luck" - and be prepared that the order might be different tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use an `ORDER BY` you cant guarantee any result order. So you probably get the order based in how the data is stored or how the planner get the data using the index

just add

```
 where MessageStatus <> 'ok' 
 order by DateDiff(minute,convert(datetime, SUBSTRING ( MSH_07_DateTime ,1 , 8 ) + ' '+ SUBSTRING ( MSH_07_DateTime ,9 , 2 ) + ':'+ SUBSTRING ( MSH_07_DateTime ,11 , 2 ), 100) 
 or 
 order by 1
```

to order using first column

Comment: Descending order is actually exactly what i need! just trying to understand why it works the way it does. This logic is not mine

Comment: The problem is you are leaving things to luck or planer implementation.  If in a later db version planner have a different algorithm you can get unexpected result. So if you data need sorting include the `order by`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specifying the ORDER BY clause then the order in which you are going to get the result is unspecified.

> If you want to rely on the order of a query, ALWAYS add ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DateDiff(minute,convert(datetime, SUBSTRING ( MSH_07_DateTime ,1 , 8 ) + ' '+ SUBSTRING ( MSH_07_DateTime ,9 , 2 ) + ':'+ SUBSTRING ( MSH_07_DateTime ,11 , 2 ), 100) as date_diff,GetDate()) 
FROM EPDBHL7.DBO.[HL7MSH] 
where MessageStatus <> 'ok' 
order by date_diff DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use an ORDER BY, you get the result in the way it is stored physically. It may be in the exact correct order but not really, programatically, ordered.

Comment: not necesary the phisical order. You can also get the order in how the index scan the table